# Customer Community license in an Enterprise edition scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, enterprise

Is it possible to have Customer Community license in an Enterprise edition scratch org? 
My DevHub Org has the licenses but when i create an Enterprise Edition scratch org, the Customer Community licenses are not available. I also tried creating a developer edition scratch org and the license in available there.
But I need them in Enterprise Edition scratch org.

Comment: Why do you need an Enterprise Edition scratch org?

Comment: Assuming that i have to use enterprise edition scratch org only, is there a way to make the licenses available during scratch org creation ?

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question I posed. We really can't help you if you can't explain why you need this. What's the problem you're trying to resolve? We can't really help you if we don't have enough details.

Comment: Because Developer Org does not allocate memory for Platform Cache and cpq that we use requires platform cached memory to work.
Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_limits.htm

Comment: Did you specific the features and settings as sucyh, @Kruthi? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/44/CommunityTemplateDefinition/scratch-def/enterprise

Comment: Yes, Have enabled communities, but we get only the high volume portal user licenses (which gives Trial customer portal user profile to select in the communities administration) @WadeWegner

Answer (score 6):

Use below configuration:

```
{
  "orgName": "Your Org Name",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": ["Communities", "**CustomerCommunityPlusLogin**", "ForceComPlatform"],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled":true,
      "ChatterEnabled":true
    }
  }
}
```

Replace CustomerCommunityPlusLogin with any Customer/Partner Community License name like CustomerCommunityPlus etc.

Comment: Not sure if you're trying to denote a placeholder with this double-asterixes, but `**LincenseName**` or `Customer Community License Name` does not work for sure.

Comment: definitely remove the `*` here