# How to add license types to entrerprise scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, licenses, scratch-org

I need to have a Partner Community license available in my scratch org.

The problem is that apparently only Developer type scratch orgs get this license by default, but I need an Enterprise type org because otherwise I hit the custom object limit on the Developer org.

Is there really no way to get a Partner Community license in an Enterprise scratch org? Or at least some way to be able to deploy partner community features like PartnerId on account, Channel objects, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try this configuration file (borrowed from answer in this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247626/customer-community-license-in-an-enterprise-edition-scratch-org) with updates on settings) :

```
{
  "orgName": "Your Org Name",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": [
    "Communities", "PartnerCommunity", "ForceComPlatform"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! I can't believe it cost me so much time just because the documentation doesn't include 'PartnerCommunity' as an option in the Feature list

Comment: @Valyrion indeed, this is not well documented. Hope it will be updated soon